React Native - FAILURE: Build failed with an exception
I keep getting the following error when attempting to build my react native application. I've attempted manually setting various versions of the Android Gradle Plugin Version and compatible Gradle Versions to no avail. However, that simply changes the gradle version in the error. The project does seem to build when I attempt to reload the project pressing 'r'.
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'TestDeleteMe'.
> Could not determine the dependencies of null.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
    > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.4.0.
        Required by:
            project :
        > No matching variant of com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.4.0 was found. The consumer was configured to find a library for use during runtime, compatible with Java 8, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally, as well as attribute 'org.gradle.plugin.api-version' with value '8.6' but:
            - Variant 'apiElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.4.0 declares a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
                - Incompatible because this component declares a component for use during compile-time, compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a component for use during runtime, compatible with Java 8
                - Other compatible attribute:
                    - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.6')
            - Variant 'javadocElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.4.0 declares a component for use during runtime, and its dependencies declared externally:
                - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
                - Other compatible attributes:
                    - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
                    - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
                    - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.6')
            - Variant 'runtimeElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.4.0 declares a library for use during runtime, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
                - Incompatible because this component declares a component, compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a component, compatible with Java 8
                - Other compatible attribute:
                    - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.6')
            - Variant 'sourcesElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.4.0 declares a component for use during runtime, and its dependencies declared externally:
                - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
                - Other compatible attributes:
                    - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
                    - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
                    - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.6')
    > Could not resolve com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin.
        Required by:
            project :
        > No matching variant of project :gradle-plugin was found. The consumer was configured to find a library for use during runtime, compatible with Java 8, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally, as well as attribute 'org.gradle.plugin.api-version' with value '8.6' but:
            - Variant 'apiElements' capability com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin:unspecified declares a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
                - Incompatible because this component declares a component for use during compile-time, compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a component for use during runtime, compatible with Java 8
                - Other compatible attribute:
                    - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.6')
            - Variant 'mainSourceElements' capability com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin:unspecified declares a component, and its dependencies declared externally:
                - Incompatible because this component declares a component of category 'verification' and the consumer needed a library
                - Other compatible attributes:
                    - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
                    - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
                    - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.6')
                    - Doesn't say anything about its usage (required runtime)
            - Variant 'runtimeElements' capability com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin:unspecified declares a library for use during runtime, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
                - Incompatible because this component declares a component, compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a component, compatible with Java 8
                - Other compatible attribute:
                    - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.6')
            - Variant 'testResultsElementsForTest' capability com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin:unspecified:
                - Incompatible because this component declares a component of category 'verification' and the consumer needed a library
                - Other compatible attributes:
                    - Doesn't say anything about how its dependencies are found (required its dependencies declared externally)
                    - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
                    - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
                    - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.6')
                    - Doesn't say anything about its usage (required runtime)
    > Could not find org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:.
        Required by:
            project :

Running npx react-native doctor I get the following:
Common
✓ Node.js - Required to execute JavaScript code
✓ npm - Required to install NPM dependencies
✓ Metro - Required for bundling the JavaScript code

Android
✓ Adb - Required to verify if the android device is attached correctly
✖ JDK - Required to compile Java code
    - Version found: N/A
    - Version supported: >= 17 <= 20
✓ Android Studio - Required for building and installing your app on Android
✓ ANDROID_HOME - Environment variable that points to your Android SDK installation
✓ Gradlew - Build tool required for Android builds
✓ Android SDK - Required for building and installing your app on Android

I believe I have JDK 17 linked correctly.

I'm not sure where the issue is.

It seems like it was a path issue. Despite having the correct JDK linked within Android Studio it seems you still need to have the correct JDK path set within your system variables in order for Metro to correctly bundle everything together.
Setting openJDK 17 as default fixed the error: archlinux-java set java-17-openjdk
